# How to not refreshing a page using angularjs when call ajax success

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to Upload File From Angularjs to webapi 
then finished upload my webpage is refresh

This my Service

```
this.setImage = function(file , refModuleId , moduleTypeId)
{
    var url = urlApiFileStorage + "api/FileStorage/SetImage";
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    fd.append('refModuleId', refModuleId);       
    fd.append('moduleType', moduleTypeId);
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url : url,
        data : fd,
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        headers : {
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'Authorize' : sessionStorage['Authorize'],
            'Content-Type' : undefined
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
      }, function(result) {
        deferred.reject('ERROR');
      });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: angularjs is used for single page applications, you don't refresh the page